# Android: Internal test app not showing up, but account is showing that its eligble

Tags: android

I uploaded an app to internal testing track to the dev console and added a user.
When I go to the app page through the link, it shows (Internal Beta). But the app version I added isn't there. Even though I got a notification that it had been processed and should be live.

So the test user is succesful, and the app was added. But even though it says I am a beta user it doesn't show any app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so I followed the test link to store, but it turns out you can't do that on your phone as it will just get you to the store app which only shows the live version. You need to follow the link on a desktop and send it to your phone from there...